# RMI exception. Cannot connect to the server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, rmi

I'm trying to connect a client and remote server through RMI and I get this error message:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
    java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at RmiClient.getMessage(RmiClient.java:11)
    at RmiClient.main(RmiClient.java:26)
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.pathToURLs(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.getDefaultCodebaseURLs(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    ... 4 more
```

The following may be the cause of the problem:

The server has this line:

```
Naming.rebind("rmi://172.31.24.66:1099/RmiServer", obj);
```

which refers to the private IP address of an EC2 instance. The client on the other hand has this line - which is line 11 from above:

```
RmiServerIntf  obj = (RmiServerIntf)Naming.lookup("rmi://54.229.66.114:1099/RmiServer");
```

which is the public IP of that instance. Also, on the client side I set the codebase property as:

```
System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.codebase", "C:\\Users\\spacitron\\Projects\\RMIClient\\bin");
```

If I try to add the same line on the server I get a "permission denied" error.

Comment: Have you tried setting **java.rmi.server.codebase** as a JVM argument instead of programmatically.  For Java 7 then try adding **-Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=false**

Comment: I get the same error. My guess is right now the problem s with the way the URL is formatted. It just doesn't recognize the prefix "rmi". If I change it do JRMP or HTTP then I can go one step further but I get an "invalid url scheme" error.

Comment: see EJP's answer =)  You need to specify it as **-Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/C:/Users/spacitron/Projects/RMIClient/bin**

Answer (score 2):

A codebase is a list of URLs. What you have specified is a file name, not a URL.

It is also a rather useless filename, unless the client is on the same host as the server, in which case it is difficult to see why you're using the codebase feature at all. Even if you have a shared drive it is just as easy to specify directories in the client's CLASSPATH as it is to use `java.rmi.server.codebase.` A codebase URL needs to be usable *by the recipient.* That's why they are almost always HTTP URLs, or maybe FTP URLs.

Comment: I wouldn't mind looking up what you said but I've been trying to to this for the last 3 days and my head is about to explode. Do you mind telling me just what do I have to type and where?

Comment: Yes I do mind. Take a break, stop, and think. For a start, think about the fact that I don't know what's on your computer or in your network. You do. You have to solve this problem. I've told you what you need to do, or not do, in general terms. It should be quitev sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

try down grading your jdk7 below update 21/jdk6 below update 45.
compile and test again of this work problem is java.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly system property
please check below link for solution for both version of jdk's

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/relnotes.html